# Undefined getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript

I have a problem which I cannot understand and cannot find a solution on my own so I need some help about this.
Been struggling about this problem...
Here's my code

```js
var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab

function showTab(n) {
  // This function will display the specified tab of the form ...
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  x[n].style.display = "block";
  // ... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
  if (n == 0) {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
  }
  if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
  }
  // ... and run a function that displays the correct step indicator:
  fixStepIndicator(n)
}

function nextPrev(n) {
  // This function will figure out which tab to display
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
  if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
  // Hide the current tab:
  x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
  // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
  currentTab = currentTab + n;
  // if you have reached the end of the form... :
  if (currentTab >= x.length) {
    //...the form gets submitted:
    document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
    return false;
  }
  // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
  showTab(currentTab);
}

function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    // If a field is empty...
    if (y[i].value == "") {
      // add an "invalid" class to the field:
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      // and set the current valid status to false:
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}

function fixStepIndicator(n) {
  // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
  var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  //... and adds the "active" class to the current step:
  x[n].className += " active";
}
```

```css
/* Style the form */
#regForm {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 100px auto;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 70%;
  min-width: 300px;
}

/* Style the input fields */
input {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

/* Mark input boxes that gets an error on validation: */
input.invalid {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}

/* Hide all steps by default: */
.tab {
  display: none;
}

/* Make circles that indicate the steps of the form: */
.step {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

/* Mark the active step: */
.step.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Mark the steps that are finished and valid: */
.step.finish {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
}
```

```html
<form id="regForm" action="">

<h1>Register:</h1>

<!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
<div class="tab">Name:
  <p><input placeholder="First name..." oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
  <p><input placeholder="Last name..." oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
</div>

<div class="tab">Contact Info:
  <p><input placeholder="E-mail..." oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
  <p><input placeholder="Phone..." oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
</div>

<div class="tab">Birthday:
  <p><input placeholder="dd" oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
  <p><input placeholder="mm" oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
  <p><input placeholder="yyyy" oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
</div>

<div class="tab">Login Info:
  <p><input placeholder="Username..." oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
  <p><input placeholder="Password..." oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
</div>

<div style="overflow:auto;">
  <div style="float:right;">
    <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
    <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
<div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
  <span class="step"></span>
  <span class="step"></span>
  <span class="step"></span>
  <span class="step"></span>
</div>

</form>
```

the console says cannot read property "className" undefined at fixStepIndicator, showTab, nextPrev, and HTMLButtonElement.onclick.

Why is it undefined? Can this be solved?

https://jsfiddle.net/kdbnqwes/

Comment: If you want to remove a class, use `x[i].classList.remove('active')`

Comment: When you're adding and removing classes, it's much better to do it using the `classList` methods rather than `className`.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: its a very long form and I don't know how to summarize it to make it a little but the problem there in html is the submit button won't respond and the console says undefined classname.. the code is copied from W3S

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a live NodeList, so it changes as classes are added and removed from the elements. But I'm not sure why that's a problem here, since you're not removing the `step` class.

Comment: Try using `x = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("step"))` to convert it to an ordinary array. Or use `document.querySelectorAll('.step')`

Comment: can you snippet it so we could tell if it's working or not?

Comment: I've tried your snippet. What do I have to do to see the error?

Comment: Is the code after "Here's my code" the same as the code in the snippet? There's no need to write it twice.

Comment: I have deleted my previous code and now its only the snippet..

Comment: I ran the snippet and didn't get any errors. What do I have to do to see the error?

Comment: The submit button won't run.. and also I want the submit button to go to other html page

Comment: The submit button ran for me. If you want it to go to another page, put its URL in the `action` attribute.

Comment: Where to put it? that submit button is just created from the next and prev buttons in the js

Comment: `<form id="regForm" action="URL you want to submit to">`

Comment: Hello again @Barmar the submit button still won't work to me.. would you care to look at it on js fiddle?

Comment: When you call `fixStepIndicator()` after the last step, there's no `x[n]`, so `x[n].className += " active";` gets an error. Didn't you see the error in the console?

Comment: Move the call to `fixStepIndicator()` into the second `else` block of `showTab()`

Comment: The fixStepIndicator() is now fixed but the others still appearing error ( at validateForm (assess.html:1124)
    at nextPrev (assess.html:1092)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (assess.html:1016))

Comment: It's time for you to learn how to use the Chrome debugger to troubleshoot this yourself.

Comment: okay, thanks for the help and sorry for troubling you